# Выпадающий список и БД (java android)

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Имеется выпадающий список(spinner) данные в этом выпадающем списке берутся из базы данных. Вопрос, как при нажатии по любому элементу из выпадающего списка получить его поля id из базы данных. P.s если что, то БД реализована с помощью sugar orm.

Код:

```
package com.example.andrei.tetsbd;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.attr.author;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView texthello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
        //Запись в БД 
        Year_inv Year = new Year_inv("03.02.2017");
        Year.save();


       //Получение id из бд и вывод его на экран через textView(ради теста)
       List<Year_inv> year_inv = Year_inv.findWithQuery(Year_inv.class, "Select ID from Yearinv where date = ?", "03.02.2017");
        String adasdasdasd = "";
        adasdasdasd += year_inv;
        texthello.setText(adasdasdasd);
    }


        //Получение данных из БД и занесение в массив "test"
        final ArrayList test= new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < years.size(); i++) {
            Year_inv date = years.get(i);
            test.add(date.date + "\n");
        }

        //Реализация выпадающего списка и заполнение его данными из БД
        Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spin.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Я бы реализовал так, что сначала данные из базы данных считал бы в массив (например ArrayList<Ваш класс>). После чего с  этого массива занес данные в Spinner по одному полю. И когда будете выбирать из списка, вы будете знать какой элемент из массива. id можно добавить как поле в классе, и будете знать какое выбрано

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский немного не понятно, как реализовать саму систему определения нажатия пользователя. Так как данные заполняются через код в MainActivity, а в интернете я находил лишь как определить что выбрал пользователь если данные spinner(выпадающего списка )заполняются через "string-array" в strings.xml

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете неверный паттерн связки `Spinner` с БД. Читать из БД потом все запихивать в `ArrayList<String>` - это неправильный подход. Надо работать с `Cursor`, для этого вам пригодится `SimpleCursorAdapter`, типа:

```
int[] adapterRowViews=new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
Cursor cursor=sdb.query(true,"mytable", new String[]{"_id", "date"},null,null,null,null,null,null);
SimpleCursorAdapter sca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor, new String[]{"date"}, adapterRowViews,0);
sca.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(sca);
```

Далее надо выставить спиннеру слушатель `onItemSelected()`:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int pos, long id) {
//blah-blah    
}
```

и внимание, `long id` параметр будет указывать на идентификатор записи (для этого требуется, чтобы идентификатор записи имел название `_ID`)

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю у вас будет чтот в роде ArrayList<Ваш класс>. Вам нужно просто по выбранному полю заполнить отдельный  string-array, и использовать в качестве адаптера. И при нажатия по списку, вы будете знать какой элемент выбран по номеру.

```
String[] statistika_string;           

         spinner_statistika = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_statistika);
                    // адаптер
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, statistika_string);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner_statistika.setAdapter(adapter);
                    // выделяем элемент
                    spinner_statistika.setSelection(0);

                    spinner_statistika.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapte

    rView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // Your code here
                 int n = spinner_statistika.getSelectedItemPosition(); //получаю позицию
                }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                return;
                }
                });
```